# GCD and mutable objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I have a singleton data manager object that manages the connection to a web service, processes the data and then updates a mutable dictionary with the objects.  All requests for this dictionary are via this singleton instance that I have created.  Now and again I will get conflicts as I am obviously editing a mutable object from many threads and so get the occasional EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I could implement @synchronized methods or use NSLock but as I am already making extensive use of Grand Central Dispatch I was wondering if there is anything I can do there by forcing them all down one thread synchronously?  I also am not sure if the above methods would work and how they would be implemented.

Example code below.  The exception can occur in the getObjectArray method as I could be adding to it/updating sub object/deleting in the translateToObjectFromDict method.

```
NSMutableDictionary *staticDictionary;

-(NSArray *)getObjectArray{

    NSArray *returnArray = [[[NSArray alloc]init]autorelease];
    returnArray = [self.staticDictionary allValues];
    return returnArray;
}

-(void)translateToObjectFromDict:(NSDictionary *)sourceDictionary{



    dispatch_group_t taskGroup = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0);


    dispatch_group_async(taskGroup,queue,^(){

    for (id key in sourceDictionary) {
        NSDictionary *subDictionary = [sourceDictionary objectForKey:key];
        for (id key in subDictionary) {

            NSArray *theObjData = [subDictionary objectForKey:key];
            if ([theObjData count] == 12) {

               theObj *temptheObj = [[PINKtheObj alloc] initWith......
                    NSString *unihex = temptheObj.unihex;

                    if ([self.staticDictionary objectForKey:unihex]){
                        PINKtheObj *localtheObj = [self.staticDictionary objectForKey:unihex];
                        if (temptheObj.time > localtheObj.time) {
                            [localtheObj updatetheObjWith.......
                        [temptheObj release];
                    }else{
                        [self.staticDictionary setObject:temptheObj forKey:unihex];
                    }
            }

        }
    }
    });

    dispatch_group_notify(taskGroup, queue, ^{
        NSDictionary *getMainDict = [self.mainDictionary objectForKey:@"theObjs"];

        for (id key in self.staticDictionary) {
            if (![getMainDict objectForKey:key]){
                [self.removeArray addObject:[self.staticDictionary objectForKey:key]];
            }
        }

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"updated" object:nil];
    });
    dispatch_release(taskGroup);

}
```

Comment: Several things wrong with this code… if you fixed them and made this thread safe you will likely have much worse performance than a naive single threaded solution. Did you try that first then determine this needs optimizing?

Comment: It is much faster than single threaded.  What is wrong with it?

Comment: it is much faster, but it doesn't work?

Comment: After adding the sync methods it is still faster than I had it in a single thread before.  I would love to know what is wrong with it though as it does work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should supply all your calls (`objectForKey:`, `setObject:ForKey:`, etc.) to your `staticDictionary` in your own serial queue. Create it when singleton initializes and use everywhere.
In your header file create ivar.

```
dispatch_queue_t queueDict;
```

In .m file just add to `init`

```
queueDict = dispatch_queue_create("com.yourid.yoursingleton.queueDict ", NULL);
```

When you want to access or put data into dictionary just make

```
dispatch_async(queueDict, ^(){
[staticDict setObject:obj forKey:key]; //example
}
```

You can use `dispatch_sync` if you want your task to wait for returned value.

```
__block id returnValue;
dispatch_sync(queueDict, ^(){
returnValue = [statictDict objectForKey:key]; //example
}
obj = returnValue;
```

Comment: OK, how do I actually do this though?  That is more of an answer to this question!

Comment: @Lee: yes this answer is correct and I use it often; if you create a private serial (non-parallel) queue all data access will be serialized. Just be sure to put on the queue the real data modifiers operations and not the parsing stuff for example in order to avoid to keep the queue blocked with too many extra tasks, especially if you use dispatch_sync().

Comment: Awesome, how come you can get away with the async for adding objects?  Will these still block a sync request? i.e. FIFO still?

Comment: All blocks are serially executed in queue. the main difference is that async does not block queue it was called from, while sync makes it to wait when task is done.

Comment: Great thanks, and will this do this on the main thread or a background thread?

Comment: Your custom queues work in background threads. If you call `dispatch_sync` from main thread it will be blocked. viggio24 told right that you should avoid heavy tasks in this "accessors" queue. Also don't forget about `autoreleasePool`.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate each request for access to the dictionary in an NSBlockOperation or NSInvocation object, then add the operation to an NSOperationQueue, setting the maximum number of concurrent operations to 1:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
    NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Doing something...");
    }];
    
    [queue addOperation:operation];
```

If there is a consistent pattern of access, such as are inherent to implementations employing the Producer-Consumer design pattern, you can create a reusable NSBlockOperation object, segregating each call to access the dictionary in their own execution block:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Doing something...");
    }];
    
    //you can add more blocks
    [operation addExecutionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Another block");
    }];
    
    [operation setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Doing something once the operation has finished...");
    }];
    
    [queue addOperation:operation];
```

An operation queue provides its own threads in which to run its operations, so there's no need to create your own. Since operation queues use GCD, operations are always executed on a separate thread, their respective designations as asynchronous and synchronous notwithstanding.

This should simplify your code, particularly by eliminating your dispatch queue-related code. What a mess!

Finally, create a global accessor method by adding the dictionary to AppDelegate that:

1. Enforces a singleton
2. Performs initialization only after a method or class references the dictionary for the first time
3. Works only on a mutable copy, creating a new, mutable dictionary afterwards to replace the previous one

Here's another option Apple suggests in its developer documentation (I copied this directly from the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW24)):

> Using Dispatch Semaphores to Regulate the Use of Finite Resources If
>   the tasks you are submitting to dispatch queues access some finite
>   resource, you may want to use a dispatch semaphore to regulate the
>   number of tasks simultaneously accessing that resource. A dispatch
>   semaphore works like a regular semaphore with one exception. When
>   resources are available, it takes less time to acquire a dispatch
>   semaphore than it does to acquire a traditional system semaphore. This
>   is because Grand Central Dispatch does not call down into the kernel
>   for this particular case. The only time it calls down into the kernel is 
>   when the resource is not available and the system needs to park your
>   thread until the semaphore is signaled. The semantics for using a
>   dispatch semaphore are as follows:
>   1. When you create the semaphore (using the dispatch_semaphore_create function), you can specify a positive integer indicating the number of
>   resources available. 
>   2. In each task, call dispatch_semaphore_waitto wait on the semaphore.
>   3. When the wait call returns, acquire the resource and do your work.
>   4. When you are done with the resource, release it and signal the semaphore by calling the dispatch_semaphore_signal function. For an
>   example of how these steps work, consider the use of file descriptors
>   on the system. Each application is given a limited number of file
>   descriptors to use. If you have a task that processes large numbers of
>   files, you do not want to open so many files at one time that you run
>   out of file descriptors. Instead, you can use a semaphore to limit the
>   number of file descriptors in use at any one time by your
>   file-processing code. The basic pieces of code you would incorporate 
>   into your tasks is as follows:  // Create the semaphore, specifying
>   the initial pool size dispatch_semaphore_t fd_sema =
>   dispatch_semaphore_create(getdtablesize() / 2);   // Wait for a free
>   file descriptor dispatch_semaphore_wait(fd_sema,
>   DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); fd = open("/etc/services", O_RDONLY);   //
>   Release the file descriptor when done close(fd);
>   dispatch_semaphore_signal(fd_sema); When you create the semaphore, you
>   specify the number of available resources. This value becomes the
>   initial count variable for the semaphore. Each time you wait on the
>   semaphore, the dispatch_semaphore_wait function decrements that count
>   variable by 1. If the resulting value is negative, the function tells
>   the kernel to block your thread. On the other end, the
>   dispatch_semaphore_signalfunction increments the count variable by 1
>   to indicate that a resource has been freed up. If there are tasks
>   blocked and waiting for a resource, one of them is subsequently 
>   unblocked and allowed to do its work.